# javascript search - hide text but can be searched

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I did a search from a tutorial that can filter in any order of words.

My HTML Code

```
    <input type="text" class="search-box">
    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Movies.Count; i++)
          {
            var movieTitle = Movies[i].Title;
            var movieAuthor = Movies[i].Author;
            <li class="item-list">@movieTitle</li>
          }
    </ul>
```

My Script

```
let inputElem = document.querySelector(".search-box");
inputElem.addEventListener("input", handleInput, false);

function handleInput() {
    
    let inputElemValue = inputElem.value.toLowerCase();

    let inputWordsArray = inputElemValue.split(" ");

    let liHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("item-list");

    Array.from(liHTMLCollection).forEach((li) => {
        let innerTextLowerCase = li.innerHTML.toLowerCase();

        let matching = true;

        inputWordsArray.forEach((word) => {
            let regex = new RegExp("\\b" + word);

            if (regex.exec(innerTextLowerCase)) {
                //if true - display
            } else {
                //if false hide
                matching = false;
            }
        });
        if (matching) {
            li.style.display = "block";

        } else {
            li.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

What I want is to concatenate `movieTitle` and `movieAuthor` but I want `movieAuthor` to be hidden in front-end but can be searchable and will appear the `movieTitle`.

Thanks for answer

Comment: I'm no expert so this is just a thought - maybe add it to output but hide it with css

Comment: @Chris it worked, thank u

Comment: Ah great - glad it worked. You could add it as an answer to your own question in case anyone else is looking. I won't because I was just guessing, you figured out what to actually do

Comment: I really think you gave the right input to get to a correct answer, @Chris you should post it as an answer :)